# SSIS OLE DB Destination Table View Fastload or normal does not give error on duplicate key

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am filling a table using a package and after preparing the data to be saved I present it to an OLEDB destination for SQL server and setting the data acces mode to Table or View - Fastload or just Table or view (no fast load).

There is no error message but it does not write to the table.
I switch over to the normal Table or View so that each record is inserted with a separate INSERT command instead of a BULK insert.
When nothing happens I stop the execution of the package and do a select * from the destination table. I saw that he inserted 20 records. After investigation the data which is send to the OLE DB destination, I saw that record 21 results in a duplicate key.
Instead of getting an error message the package does not continue its execution flow.
What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through all the elements of the package, including the package itself, and set:

```
FailPackageOnFailure = True
```